# what is the difference between null != object and object!=null

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [which way is better “null != object” or “ object != null”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957836/which-way-is-better-null-object-or-object-null)
>   [Why does one often see “null != variable” instead of “variable != null” in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c)
>   [‘ … != null’  or  ‘null != …’ best performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398588/null-or-null-best-performance)

Please guide me.
what is the difference between null != object and object!=null
same for "".equal("something") and "something".equals("")

which one is good for processing.

Comment: Yoda would use the first version of each, other than that, no difference.  The second one however, if the first string was null you would have a party in the error log...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957836/which-way-is-better-null-object-or-object-null-closed

Comment: Weird grammatics "Yoda Conditions" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378?tab=votes&page=1#tab-top

Answer (score 29):

The first two are equivalent, but the "null != object" is an old practice from languages where it is valid to write "if (object = null)" and accidentally assign null to the object. It is a guard to stop this accident from happening.

The second whilst equivalent has the added advantage that if "something" is null you will not get a null reference exception whereas you would if you did: something".equals("").

Comment: Speed me for several seconds. ;)

Comment: "null != object" also helps the reader parse the condition, because more often than not the "object" part is a more complex expression.

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely no difference in either semantics or performance.

The `==` in this case is a reference inequality operation; it can never throw `NullPointerException`.

> #### [JLS 15.21.3 Reference Equality Operators == and !=](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.3)
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.
>
> The result of `!=` is `false` if the operand values are both `null` or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is `true`.

Use whatever is most readable. Usually it's `something != null`.

#### Related questions

- [‘ … != null’ or ‘null != …’ best performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398588/null-or-null-best-performance/)

Comment: null then object is faster than object then null