# Difference between null==object and object==null

Tags: java, object, null, compare, nullpointerexception

Hi I would like to know diff between the above comparisons?

I am getting null pointer exception when I check `object.getItems() == null`.
But if I change it to `null == object.getItems()`, it workes fine.

I did look into this [what is the difference between null != object and object!=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938476/what-is-the-difference-between-null-object-and-objectnull-closed)
But I didnt get satisfactory answer.

Comment: No, that change won't change if a NPE is thrown or not. Re-check your assumptions, because those two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: I get NPE both ways. What exactly is null when you try it, object?

Comment: Please post the complete Java statement, maybe the problem is just a misplaced/missing bracket.

Comment: It will be `object` that is null or a problem within getItems().

Comment: Problem with getItems(). I know object is not null.

Comment: @priyank.mp: Even a problem *inside* `getItems()` wouldn't make those two expressions any different. `getItems()` would be called *in both expressions*.

Comment: Could you post your object.getItems() code. I suspect there is something in that method throws NullPointerException.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sup>(Similar question: [Which is more effective: if (null == variable) or if (variable == null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021195/which-is-more-effective-if-null-variable-or-if-variable-null))</sup>

> Difference between null==object and object==null

There is no semantical difference.

`object.getItems() == null`  and   `null == object.getItems()`   are equivalent.

Perhaps you're mixing it up with the fact that

```
nonNullObj.equals(obj)
```

and

```
obj.equals(nonNullObj)
```

can make a difference (since the second alternative could result in a NPE in case the callee is null).

Comment: what is the reason second expressoin NPE

Comment: @Rozer, if obj is null, then the .equals method call would result in an NPE.