# What's the comparison difference?

Tags: java, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Null check in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/null-check-in-java)

I'm just wondering what's the difference between

```
if (null == something) {...}
```

and

```
if (something == null) {...}
```

assuming that in both cases `something` is the same object. Presumably, there should be non, except for readability of the code.

Comment: No diff. considering behaviors and performance

Comment: This question shows again that the simpler the question, the higher the noise. 2 wrong answers of the first 4 answers, because everyone rushes to give it a shot.

Comment: See [Null check in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/null-check-in-java)

Comment: I also had a similar problem
[here is what I got as answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398588/null-or-null-best-performance)

Comment: @John That's not Yoda Syntax.  Yoda syntax is constant.equals(variable).  For == it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

The idea of putting the constant first helps guard against accidental assignment in the condition.  For example in some languages it is valid to say:

```
if (i = 42) {
    ...
}
```

i is assigned and the condition is true.  If you didn't mean to do this, there is no compiler error and it can be difficult to find.

If you instead always put the constant first:

```
if (42 == i) {
    ...
}
```

Then the day you accidentally do:

```
if (42 = i) {
    ...
}
```

A compiler error will alert you immediately that you are attempting to assign to a constant.

Comment: It's also possible to assign in the condition of a Java `if` statement, if the type of the variable being assigned is `boolean`

Comment: good answer to where it came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/null-check-in-java

Answer (score 7):

The statements are completly equivalent.

Differences occure only when using equals, and then null is never used explicitely.

```
if( "A".equals(someString) ) { ... }
```

is null safe, since it doesn't fail if someString is null.

```
if( someString.equals("A") ) { ... }
```

will obviously fail when someString is null.

Comment: Well, the question is not about equals method.

Comment: Yes, but the questioner had the vague idea in mind that changing the operands of an comparison would result in differences, so I pointed out, where he might have seen that concept and where it is appliable.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this StackOverflow question: [object==null or null==object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/null-check-in-java). It covers the answer of your question.

Comment: Great link, explains where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

This is just to guard against the common mistake of using `=` in place of `==`.

```
if (true = something) {...}
```

gives an error but

```
if (something = true) {...}
```

does not, assuming `something` is a boolean variable.

Comment: -1 The second will also give an error. Again, this is Java not C.

Comment: @Daniel: not if `something` is a boolean (which it is if you are assigning true to it).  Your down vote is erroneous.

Comment: @JeremyP: My initial answer was wrong: `if (something = null)` :)

Comment: @codaddict: OK, but the down vote is still erroneous *now*.

Comment: Bug in stackoverflow? I just tried to undownvote, but my vote is locked now, because "the answer has not been edited" (which seems wrong).

Comment: @Daniel : It might be someone else -1.

Comment: @codaddict there is no boolean with boolean comparison in java as of common use. Assuming that something is boolean value, common use is like next: if (something) {...}, so we're talking only about null values which means that this answer is still missing the point.