# Coding standard for null checking

Tags: java, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the comparison difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030766/whats-the-comparison-difference)
>   [Null check in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369226/null-check-in-java)

Most of the developers have the habit of writing the null checking with null in the left hand side.like,

```
if(null == someVariable)
```

Does this help any way? According to me this is affecting the readability of the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021195/which-is-more-effective-ifnullvariables-or-ifvariablesnull/3021208#3021208

Comment: It's called "Yoda conditions" ! :D

Comment: You mean, "Yoda Conditions, its called."

Comment: 'Most of the developers'. Really? Evidence?

Comment: @EJP: Yeah, I don't see it very often at all. Perhaps it's most of the developers in his organization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it has no purpose whatsoever in Java.

In C and some of its related languages, it was sometimes used to avoid making this mistake:

```
if (someVariable = null)
```

Note the `=` rather than `==`, the author has inadvertently assigned `null` to `someVariable` rather than checking for `null`. But that will result in a compiler error in Java.

Even in C, any modern compiler will have an option to treat the `if (someVariable = null)` as a warning (or even an error).

Stylistically, I agree with you — I wouldn't say "if 21 you are, I will serve you a drink" (unless I'd already had <s>a couple</s> several and was doing my Yoda impersonation). Mind you, that's English; for all I know it would make perfect sense in other languages, in which case it would be perfectly reasonable style for speakers of those languages.

Comment: @TJCrowder, to say it has `no purpose whatsoever in java` would be slightly wrong....If the `someVariable` is a `Boolean`, it doesn't throw a compile error...:) You'll need to Yoda that out...but otherwise java cleans up for you. :)

Comment: @st0le: Wow, I'm astonished to find that you're right about that. I did not know that (and have checked it). Thank you! But I'd counter with: Don't test booleans that way, there's no purpose whatsoever to `if (someVariable == true)`, simply use `if (someVariable)` (and of course the `!someVariable` instead of comparing to `false`). (And the fact you can have an inadvertent assignment supports using that style.) The only time I'd use `=` or `!=` with booleans would be if I were comparing two variables (not comparing to a constant), and the construct wouldn't help me there. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder, well ofcourse, no decent java programmer will actually use that...I was merely throwing an exception, pun intended ;)

Comment: @st0le: Yeah, thanks again. I was so surprised when I wrote a test case for it and it passed. :-)

Answer (score 5):

It used to help in 'the olden days' when C compilers would not complain about missing an `=`, when wanting `==`:

```
// OOps forgot an equals, and got assignment
if (someVariable = null) 
{
}
```

Any modern C#/Java/C++/C compiler should raise a warning (and hopefully an error).

Personally, I find

```
if (someVariable == null) 
{
}
```

more readable than starting with the `null`.

Comment: (Speaking of C and C++ compilers): an error, not a warning?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I don't see any merit in doing that way. But I prefer the following...

```
if("a string".equals(strVariable))
{
}
```

over this..

```
if(strVariable != null && strVariable.equals("a string"))
{
}
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - yes, it is defined in the contract. From the very link you provided: "For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false."

Comment: @T.J. Crowder & @Cowan, yes I went back as far as JDK 1.1.1 and it is defined in the contract. http://www.tns.lcs.mit.edu/manuals/java-1.1.1/api/java.lang.Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @Cowan & @Rosdi: I can't believe I've missed that all these years. Thanks. I've removed the earlier comment. Proof that you never stop learning. **Man** do those docs need rewording, all of the unnecessary reiteration of "for any non-null x" totally obscures the remaining points. And sadly, I've met quite a number of contract-breaking implementations of `equals` over the years. :-(